# How can we send data into correct object item

Tags: javascript

While saving the `testuniquename` it is always saving to the first item ie `autoId`. While sending the data, how can we save into the correct object key ie autoId should be passed into autoId and testuniquename should be passed into testuniquename ?

`localStorage.js`

```
let localStorageData = {};

function saveLocalStorageData (autoId, testuniquename) {
    localStorageData = {
        autoId: autoId,
        testuniquename: testuniquename,
    }
    return localStorageData
}

export { saveLocalStorageData };
```

`random.js`

```
let localData = require("../../../support/localStorage");

let testuniquename= {};
testuniquename= "SomeAutomationText"
const localStorageData =   localData.saveLocalStorageData(testuniquename);
window.localStorage.setItem('localStorageData', JSON.stringify(localStorageData));
```

`register.js`

```
let localData = require("../../../support/localStorage");

    let autoId = {};
    autoId = "345"
    const localStorageData =   localData.saveLocalStorageData(autoId);
    window.localStorage.setItem('localStorageData', JSON.stringify(localStorageData));
```

Comment: Why are you saving it as a json?

Comment: Someone technically advise me to save as json , sorry is that not correct ?

Comment: There is not a definite correct method to do a certain thing, but for me, since local storage itself is already using a key-value pair to save data, I will just use two keys, `autoId` and `testuniquename` to save them instead of combining them into one json value as it is more difficult to manage

Comment: Using your question as an example, I can easily do `window.localStorage.setItem('autoId', 'random_key');` to save the value instead of serializing it into a json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass an object to `saveLocalStorageData` insted of 2 inputs. Someting like:

```
function saveLocalStorageData (obj) {
    localStorageData = {
        autoId: obj.autoId,
        testuniquename: obj.testuniquename,
    }
    return localStorageData
}

export { saveLocalStorageData };
```

Then:

**random.js**

```
let localData = require("../../../support/localStorage");

let obj = {autoId: "", testuniquename: "SomeAutomationText"};
const localStorageData =   localData.saveLocalStorageData(obj);
window.localStorage.setItem('localStorageData', JSON.stringify(localStorageData));
```

**register.js**

```
let localData = require("../../../support/localStorage");

let obj = {autoId: "345", testuniquename: ""};
const localStorageData =   localData.saveLocalStorageData(obj);
window.localStorage.setItem('localStorageData', JSON.stringify(localStorageData));
```

Comment: Here we should remember to pass either one of the value to be `null / blank ` right `let obj = {autoId: "", testuniquename: "SomeAutomationText"};`

Comment: @soccerway exactly. Of course the value depends on your logic...

Comment: Ok if you pass as an object , can I retrieve like `let id = obj.autoId  and obj.testuniquename `  ?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the parameter in `saveLocalStorage` function to take in an object,

```
let localStorageData = {};

function saveLocalStorageData ({autoId, testuniquename}) {
    localStorageData = {
        autoId: autoId, // notice that if you do not pass in autoId, this value will be null
        testuniquename: testuniquename,
    }
    return localStorageData
}

export { saveLocalStorageData };
```

Then every time you wanna call it,

```
const localStorageData = localData.saveLocalStorageData({autoId});
```

Although I do not think saving value as json in local storage is recommended since local storage itself is already a key-value pair architecture.